# HTML5 section touchstart touchmove touchend iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom-events, touch-event

Please somebody help me with this:

```
touchStart = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("touched");
};

touchEnd = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("touched");
};

s.ontouchstart = touchStart;
s.ontouchend = touchEnd;
s.ontouchmove = touchEnd;
```

I have a section element, generated dynamically by JavaScript (ul > li > section). When I'm binding a touchstart-touchmove-touchend event listener to this section element, it works on Android, but not on iPad/iPod/iPhone.

I have tried generating it with `onclick="void(0)"` attribute, it made the section element "interact" like a clickable element but it still does nothing.

It works on Android every way but this vegetable seems a little consume useless to me now... =)

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, got it with jQuery. This way it runs everywhere.

```
$(s).bind("touchstart mousedown", function (e) {
    console.log(e.type); // to get the name of the event
}).bind("touchmove mousemove", function (e) {
    // ...
}).bind("touchend mouseup", function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That code will fire twice in a touch-enabled browser.  Check it out: $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').bind("touchstart mousedown", function (e) {
          console.log("test " + Date.now());
        });
      });

Comment: yupp, the final solution handles it =)

Comment: doesnt seem to work for $('.slider ul li').bind("touchstart mousedown", function (e) {
        console.log(e.type); // to get the name of the event
    }).bind("touchmove mousemove", function (e) {
        console.log(e.type); 
    }).bind("touchend mouseup", function (e) {
        console.log(e.type); 
    });